# Single Parse query with a where clause on a child object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is a specific case of a general problem of querying in Parse a parent object using where conditions on a child object.

I have two related Parse objects - **jobs** and **jobLocations**. Jobs may have many jobLocations.  The jobLocations Parse object has a pointer to its parent job. I'm trying to issue a single query (in a PFQueryCollectionViewController) to return a list of Jobs with locations within a certain distance from my current location.

Code as follows:

```
var locationQuery = PFQuery(className: "jobLocations")
locationQuery.whereKey("geoLocation", nearGeoPoint: myLocation, withinKilometers: localDistance)
locationQuery.includeKey("parentJob")

var query = PFQuery(className: "jobs")
query.whereKey("objectId", matchesKey: "parentJob", inQuery: locationQuery)
```

The locationQuery successfully finds the right jobLocations but I can't figure out the way to use these in the query on Jobs. The code above doesn't seem return any matching jobs. I have also tried:

```
query.whereKey("objectId", matchesKey: "parentJob.objectId", inQuery: locationQuery)
```

... but the dot notation doesn't seem to work in whereKey

Have studied the Parse documentation and googled it but can't locate an example.

Obviously I could store the results of the location query in an array then use this in the where key for the job query but I need a single query to use in a PFQueryCollectionViewController.

Comment: I think you shouldn't need the second query at all, the 'includeKey("parentJob")' should return the related jobs object as a part of the result. Can u try accessing the parentJob attribute in the completion block?

Comment: Thank. I can, but since this is in a collection view controller that displays a list of jobs, not jobLocations, I'd like a single query that returns jobs, not job locations. Otherwise I get duplicate cells - i.e. the same job appears many times - once for each location.

Comment: Ok got it. Why don't you try instead a jobLocation object with an array of pointers to related jobs? You can place location query with includeKey on the array of pointers. That should work in CollectionView ...

Comment: Not sure I understand. At the moment each job location is associated with only one job so I have a single pointer. How would an array of pointers help? Did you mean implement the relationship the other way around - i.e. on the job object include an array of pointers to its job locations?

Comment: Hm you're right. Your current query design is not supported by Parse (comparing string 'objectId' to returned whole objects). One workaround is to store with your parentJob pointer also string 'objectId' of the pointed jobs object (that allows you to compare string to string) but thats clumsy. The solutions danh proposed seem like the best option so far.

Answer (score 0):

If Job has an array of pointers to JobLocation, then you can use whereKeyMatchesQuery.  Form an inner query as you have it on JobLocation based on nearness to some position, then form a query on Job  `whereKey("locations", matchesQuery: locationQuery)`.

If the one-to-many relation is represented only by a pointer from location to Job (which is reasonable), then you must query JobLocation as you have it and `includeKey("parentJob")`.  Loop through the found objects and gather their parentJobs into an array that is the datasource for your table.

Comment: Thanks. I may need to implement the relationship the other way around (as per the first part of your comment). The second part won't work in this scenario as I need a single query for a PFQueryViewCollectionViewController.